# DNS Taking a couple of attempts to resolve everytime

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008

I seem to be having some issues with my domain controller when trying to resolve hostnames using dns. It does seem to work but it always takes a couple of attempts, even if its a hostname i have already resolved. I have been noticing it with webpages and downloads.

Here is a nslookup test i did

```
C:\Users\chris.townsend>nslookup abc.com
Server:  dc.example.com
Address:  192.168.101.20

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to dc.example.com timed-out

C:\Users\chris.townsend>nslookup abc.com
Server:  dc.example.com
Address:  192.168.101.20

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    abc.com
Address:  199.181.132.250
```

Some sites it works first time and some it takes a couple more. I cant seem to figure it out and its the same on all the systems in our office.  Restarting and /dnsflush dont seem to make any diffence either.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: just incase anyone else has this same issue : this is what we found out it was - we use a watch guard router and it seemed to be proxies causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just incase anyone else has this same issue : this is what we found out it was - we use a watch guard router and it seemed to be proxies causing this issue